# Difference between phablet-flash cdimage-touch and phablet-flash ubuntu-system?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I always used the method: **phablet-flash cdimage-touch** for updating to the newest version.

But there is also the possibility to use: **phablet-flash ubuntu-system**.

So my question is: Where is the difference between "cdimage" and "ubuntu-system"?

Are there any pros or cons?

Comment: Note: if you are not sure whether your device is running ubuntu-system or cdimage-touch, here are two tests: 1) /android only exists in ubuntu-system images; 2) 'system-image-cli -i' returns a Build number of 1 or higher on ubuntu-system images and 0 on cdimage-touch images (because only ubuntu-system images are numbered).

Comment: @david6 you sure we **need** this tag? as far it goes both questions are about ubuntu-touch and there isn't a big sub-group of questions that would need this tag.

Comment: This is new. I'm not sure I like it, and they want to adopt this update method for Ubuntu (desktop). *So, YES, I do think it is important.*

Answer (score 3):

- cdimage-touch

Provisions the device with a CDimage build of Ubuntu Touch.

- cdimage-legacy

Provisions the device with legacy unflipped images. These images really shouldn't be used anymore, but it's a good time machine.

- ubuntu-system

Provisions the device with an Ubuntu Image Based Upgrade image. If you still don't know what this is, refer to [Stephane's blog post](https://daniel.holba.ch/blog/tag/porting/) or [the wiki describing it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImageBasedUpgrades).

From the link:

> Some of you may be aware that I along with Barry Warsaw and Ondrej Kubik have been working on image based upgrades for Ubuntu Touch. **This is going to be the official method to update any Ubuntu Touch devices**. When using this system, the system will effectively be read-only with updates being downloaded over the air from a central server and applied in a consistent way across all devices. Design details may be found at: http://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImageBasedUpgrades
>
> After several months of careful design and implementation, we are now ready to get more testers. We are producing daily images for our 4 usual devices, Galaxy Nexus (maguro), Nexus 4 (mako), Nexus 7 (grouper) and Nexus 10 (manta). At this point, only those devices are supported. We’ll soon be working with the various ports to see how to get them running on the new system.

- community

Provisions the device with a community supported build. Community based images as described by Daniel on his blog. In a nutshell, each porter provides a manifest of where their ports are located and the are provisioned to the target devices, this currently only works with recovery images that support extendedcommands. Support for openrecoverscript is one of the close targets.

---

ubuntu-system will be the official one. So this is better support, regular updates and easier setup.